# how to get birthday date in mysql query (condition is if your birthday is today means to know it before two days itself)?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT username, dob FROM userdetails 
WHERE  
(MONTH(dob), DAY(dob)) = (MONTH(CURDATE()),DAY(CURDATE()))
```

above query I tried to get CURDATE birthday person's username & DOB it's working But, actually My need is If the person have b'day today i wan't to know it two days before itself. I stuck up here so, kindly help me please ????

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
SELECT username, dob FROM userdetails WHERE
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', MONTH(dob), '-', DAY(dob) ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT username, dob FROM userdetails WHERE DAY(dob) = DAY(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AND MONTH(dob) = MONTH(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))

Comment: Adarsh, your query execute when database dob equal to current data. Eg, if i have three dob records in my DB like these 15-10-1992 , 15-10-19988 & 15-10-2015. if i apply your query it's will return only 15-10-2015 bcoz in condition you compare year But, anyway I'm happy for your response..

Comment: @Ashok, it was a stupidity, see the correct one its edited

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM user_login_details
WHERE
DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW());

Comment: use it like this SELECT * FROM user_login_details WHERE DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY); Because you need to add 2 days to both places when you find day and month from NOW()

Comment: if the birth date is 1980-10-01, if you calculate with your query on 2015-10-29 you will get day as 29 and month as same 9 which is wrong. So you need to add 2 days to NOW() for month also. SO you will get month=10 and day=01

Comment: day as 29 okay but how U said month as 9.. In condition I given    DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY)                                                        AND MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) .. I compare db dob day = curdate + INTERVAL 2 DAY  and db dob month = current month..